# git deleted files are still listed in workspace

Tags: git, delete-file

Some files are deleted (by tortoiseGit) and commit the changes,  zip whole workspace and move the zipped file to another PC.
After unzip the workspace on the other PC I found the deleted files are still listed in the workspace.

Why and what should I do?

Comment: You could clarify what you mean by "in the project". What sort of project? Do you mean the files exist in the working directory on the second computer? Or are they listed in some IDE project file that you're not describing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete files from git you need to do a git rm or a git remove.

Since you are using tortoise I will assume you are using windows and can't simply run `git rm myfile.txt`

Instead of deleting them normally you have to delete/remove them using tortoise or they will come back.

After deleting them you need to commit the deleted files so the "delete change" is permanent.

Hope that helps.

Comment: the changes are committed.

Comment: In that case I would suggest the IDE you are using (gonna guess eclipse or something) is adding the files back.